# Can a submerged place in the sea have huge air pockets?

Tags: water, popular-science

I know that air can be under water if there is something to contain it that prevents its escape. But can a place such as buildings or ancient ruins submerged totally under water hold air pockets as bigger as a room?
I recently saw a home-made-video-of-sorts that claimed to have discovered a underwater ruin and showed its interior rooms absolutely devoid of water full of air. Is that even possible, to have an underwater ruin with a room full of air? I mean air has got to escape from somewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13141/2451

Comment: yeah I have seen this one before posting, however I don't understand how a building or an ancient structure could possibly be air tight at such high pressures under sea

Comment: In light of the emphasis of long-term stability of air pockets, I suppose this is not a duplicate. That said, it's hard to answer without specifics - what kind of ruin? how old? is it really underwater *all the time*?

Comment: @ChrisWhite well it's at least 3000 years old ruin which has always been under water for more than 1000 years